# AJAX filled pulldown shows 5 identical options when there are 5 different options in database

Tags: sql, ajax, linq, controller

Scratching head here. I've got a pulldown and if I query it in SQL Server Manager Query Window I get 5 different values (these are sample points for a water system).

However, when the pulldown loads, there are 5 options of the first value. Can someone see something I can't?

I narrowed it down to the code below because I held my cursor over "results" which was the final step in my Controller's code, and it showed 5 items all of the same value:

```
 else if ((sampletype == "P") || (sampletype == "T") || (sampletype == "C") || (sampletype == "A"))
            {
                var SamplePoints = (from c in _db.tblPWS_WSF_SPID_ISN_Lookup
                                    where c.PWS == id && c.WSFStateCode.Substring(0, 1) == "S"
                                    select c).ToList();
                if (SamplePoints.Any())
                {
                    var listItemsBig = SamplePoints.Select(p => new SelectListItem
                        {
                            Selected = false,
                            Text = p.WSFStateCode.ToString() + ":::" + p.SamplePointID.ToString(),
                            Value = p.WSFStateCode.ToString()
                        }).ToList();


                       results = new JsonResult { Data = listItemsBig };

                }

            }        

            return  results ;

        }
```

Comment: If you debug your code and check the contents of your SamplePoints variable, do you have 5 different results as well?

Comment: Thanks, I just looked and, no, they are all the same for the sample points variable. So the problem is somewhere here:



                var SamplePoints = (from c in _db.tblPWS_WSF_SPID_ISN_Lookup
                                    where c.PWS == id && c.WSFStateCode.Substring(0, 1) == "S"
                                    select c).ToList();

Comment: And what sql query do you run to get your 5 records?

Comment: SELECT PWS, WSFStateCode, SamplePointID FROM dbo.tblPWS_WSF_SPID_ISN_Lookup
WHERE PWS ='99999' AND LEFT(WSFStateCode,1) ='S'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had a similar problem in nHibernate, it was caused by how I defined my primary keys/foreign keys in the ORM, leading to a bad join and duplicate values.

Comment: Yes. I'm thinking something like that but it is only one table, no joins and PWS is the Entity Key and indexed key in SQL Server table.

Comment: I'm thinking maybe PWS is not the way to set Entity Key because it's not unique. In this case, there are 5 rows all with same PWS

Comment: Yes! Thank you cslecours!
I put an Entity Key in EF on 3 columns, PWS, WSFStateCode, and SamplePointID and it returned the correct values. I also put an index on those 3 columns in the SQL Server database.

Comment: Just an after comment. I took off the 3 column index in SQL Server and left it in EF in VS 2010 and it still worked good.